# POST request containing CSR fails in Bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, post, scripting

I've written a bash script that sends a POST request to a server. The request contains a certificate signing request and the server signs it and returns a certificate.
**When I copy and paste the CSR text in the POST's body, then the POST request is successful. But when I read the CSR from a variable, then the POST request fails.** I've attached a snippet of the program below.

**PROGRAM - Bash**

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out cert.csr -keyout priv.key -subj "/C=MyCountry/ST=MyState/L=MyCity/O=MyCompany/OU=MyDept/CN=MyComp"
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
  csr=$(<cert.csr)
fi
response=$(curl -o - -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -X POST \
https://xxx.xxx.com/URI-END-POINT \
-H "authorization: $token" \
-H "content-type: application/json" \
-d '{
  "digicert": {
  "csr": "'$csr'",
  "profileName": "pn123",
  "signatureHash": "sh123",
  "userPrincipalName": "pn123",
  "validationScopeId": "vsi123"
  },
"IccId": "sim123",
"MacAddress": "mac123"
}')
if [ $?==0 ]; then
  status=$(echo $response | tail -c 4)
  if [ "$status" == "$http_success" ]; then
      echo -e "Request for certificate SUCCESS"
  else
      echo -e "Request for certificate FAILED with return code $status"
  fi
else
  echo -e "Request for certificate FAILED"
fi
```

**OUTPUT - Bash**

```
curl: option -----END: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

In the above script, if I replace the line *"csr": "'$csr'",* with *"csr": "----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST---- XXXXXXX ----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST----"*, then this will work fine.

Can you help me debug this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the string in $csr is being evaluated, like if put in double quotes and the resulting string is something different than expected.
For start, try to see if $csr is same as "$csr".

Comment: Hi Klemen
See @chepner's answer for a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

To post the contents of a file, use `jq` to generate the JSON blob for you: this will take care of any necessary quoting automatically. The output of `jq` is pipe directly to `curl` by using the `@-` argument for the `-d` option. (A `@`-prefixed string indicates the name of a file `curl` should read from; `-` is the alias for standard input.)

```
response=$(jq -n --arg csr "$(<csr)" '{
                                     digicert: {
                                       csr: $csr,
                                       profileName: "pn123",
                                       signatureHash : "sh123",
                                       userPrincipalName: "pn123",
                                       validationScopeId: "vsi123"
                                     },
                                     IccId: "sim123",
                                     MacAddress: "mac123"
                                   }' |
            curl -o - -s -w "%{http_code}\n" -X POST \
                https://xxx.xxx.com/URI-END-POINT \
                -H "authorization: $token" \
                -H "content-type: application/json" \
                -d @-
)
```

Comment: Thank you @chepner. I had to add a "-n" option to the jq command, which as per the jq manual does:
`Don’t read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run once using null as the input. This is useful when using jq as a simple calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch.`

Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, about that. That's what I get for rewriting this answer from memory again. I really need to find or create a canonical version of this.