# Post request in JSON using cURL fails

Tags: json, bash, shell, curl, csr

I'm struggling to generate a proper JSON POST request using cURL. For that purpose I'm writing a short shell script to do so but apparently there seems to be a problem with my JSON-string (according to the error message I listed below).

If I write the CSR directly into the JSON string, it will work just fine:

```bash
authToken="Here'sMyAuthToken"
curl --data-binary '{"authToken" : "'$authToken'", "order" : {"type" : "DomainValidatedCertificateOrder", "csr" : "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
certificaterequestkey
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----", "adminContact" : {"title" : "mytitle", "firstName" : "myfirstname", "lastName" : "mylastname", "phoneNumber" : "X0000000", "emailAddress" : "test@example.com"}, "techContact" : {"title" : "mytitle", "firstName" : "myfirstname", "lastName" : "mylastname", "phoneNumber" : "000000000", "emailAddress" : "test@example.com"}, "productCode" : "ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m", "validationType" : "validateViaDns", "approverEmailAddress" : "postmaster@example.com", "autoRenew" : false}}' -i -X POST https://partner.http.net/api/ssl/v1/json/orderCreate
```

However, if I pass the CSR over by reading the csr file directly like this

```bash
authToken="Here'sMyAuthToken"
csr=$(<csr.csr)
curl --data-binary '{"authToken" : "'$authToken'", "order" : {"type" : "DomainValidatedCertificateOrder", "csr" : "'$csr'", "adminContact" : {"title" : "mytitle", "firstName" : "myfirstname", "lastName" : "mylastname", "phoneNumber" : "X0000000", "emailAddress" : "test@example.com"}, "techContact" : {"title" : "mytitle", "firstName" : "myfirstname", "lastName" : "mylastname", "phoneNumber" : "000000000", "emailAddress" : "test@example.com"}, "productCode" : "ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m", "validationType" : "validateViaDns", "approverEmailAddress" : "postmaster@example.com", "autoRenew" : false}}' -i -X POST https://partner.http.net/api/ssl/v1/json/orderCreate
```

it will give me the following error.

```bash
curl: option -----END: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

I've already found a case where someone had the exact same problem like me here:

[POST request containing CSR fails in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45871569/post-request-containing-csr-fails-in-bash)

The user accomplished solving this problem using the `jq` package. Unfortunately I can't install this package on the machine the script is supposed to run since I'm not allowed to install any packages at all.
Could someone give an advice how to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I added an answer because the others did not mention the required header for a JSON post request.   Also I thought because you were using a a command line curl, you probably only need the command line escaped and organized so it would work.   Apparently this site has a hard time dealing with the escaped string.  I got so many errors when I tried to save the edits. I was trying to exit and I had to give up. And my post is almost there.  I did a lot of testing using my curl debug web app to verify the curl code.  This url will give you details about the post: http://eatled.com/receiveheader.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been having a very hard time posting.  I kept getting Errors when saving.

This is the request and response with a `Content-Type: application/json` in the HTTP request header:

```
Content-Length: 540
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Host: eatled.com


BODY={"authToken": "$authToken","order": {"type": "DomainValidatedCertificateOrder","csr": "$csr","adminContact": {"title": "mytitle","firstName": "myfirstname","lastName": "mylastname","phoneNumber": "X0000000","emailAddress": "test@example.com"},"techContact": {"title": "mytitle","firstName": "myfirstname","lastName": "mylastname","phoneNumber": "000000000","emailAddress": "test@example.com"},"productCode": "ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m","validationType": "validateViaDns","approverEmailAddress": "postmaster@example.com","autoRenew": false}}
```

I removed the Content-Type and this is the request and response.
Notice how the header changed to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and how the JSON is in the KEY of the $_POST data as it was received by the Server.  When the server sees the form data header it will may process try to process the request as if it were a form. It depends upon how well the API was written.

```
Content-Length: 540
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip, br
Host: eatled.com

$_POST
array (
  '{"authToken":_"$authToken","order":_{"type":_"DomainValidatedCertificateOrder","csr":_"$csr","adminContact":_{"title":_"mytitle","firstName":_"myfirstname","lastName":_"mylastname","phoneNumber":_"X0000000","emailAddress":_"test@example_com"},"techContact":_{"title":_"mytitle","firstName":_"myfirstname","lastName":_"mylastname","phoneNumber":_"000000000","emailAddress":_"test@example_com"},"productCode":_"ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m","validationType":_"validateViaDns","approverEmailAddress":_"postmaster@example_com","autoRenew":_false}}' => '',
)
```

This is your curl code with all the escape codes and the options reorganized because the you had them generated an error.  This is tested, and works.

```
curl  -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST http://eatled.com/receiveheader.php --data-binary "{\"authToken\": \"$authToken\",\"order\": {\"type\": \"DomainValidatedCertificateOrder\",\"csr\": \"$csr\",\"adminContact\": {\"title\": \"mytitle\",\"firstName\": \"myfirstname\",\"lastName\": \"mylastname\",\"phoneNumber\": \"X0000000\",\"emailAddress\": \"test@example.com\"},\"techContact\": {\"title\": \"mytitle\",\"firstName\": \"myfirstname\",\"lastName\": \"mylastname\",\"phoneNumber\": \"000000000\",\"emailAddress\": \"test@example.com\"},\"productCode\": \"ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m\",\"validationType\": \"validateViaDns\",\"approverEmailAddress\": \"postmaster@example.com\",\"autoRenew\": false}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are misquoting things in your command line.  You're making frequent use of this sort of structure:

```
'{"somekey": "'$variable'"}'
```

That means that you're *not* quoting `$somevariable`, so if it contains whitespace you're going to end up with a command other than what you expect. You need to quote all your variables, so the above becomes:

```
'{"somekey": "'"$variable"'"}'
```

And your full command line is:

```
curl --data-binary '
  {
    "authToken" : "'"$authToken"'",
    "order" : {
      "type" : "DomainValidatedCertificateOrder",
      "csr" : "'"$csr"'",
      "adminContact" : {
        "title" : "mytitle",
        "firstName" : "myfirstname",
        "lastName" : "mylastname",
        "phoneNumber" : "X0000000",
        "emailAddress" : "test@example.com"
      },
      "techContact" : {
        "title" : "mytitle",
        "firstName" : "myfirstname",
        "lastName" : "mylastname",
        "phoneNumber" : "000000000",
        "emailAddress" : "test@example.com"
      },
      "productCode" : "ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m",
      "validationType" : "validateViaDns",
      "approverEmailAddress" : "postmaster@example.com",
      "autoRenew" : false
    }
  }
  ' -i -X POST https://partner.http.net/api/ssl/v1/json/orderCreate
```

---

You could simplify things by using a *[here document](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)* instead of trying to embed everything on the command line. That would look like:

```
curl -i -X POST --data-binary @- https://partner.http.net/api/ssl/v1/json/orderCreate <<EOF
{
  "authToken": "$authToken",
  "order": {
    "type": "DomainValidatedCertificateOrder",
    "csr": "$csr",
    "adminContact": {
      "title": "mytitle",
      "firstName": "myfirstname",
      "lastName": "mylastname",
      "phoneNumber": "X0000000",
      "emailAddress": "test@example.com"
    },
    "techContact": {
      "title": "mytitle",
      "firstName": "myfirstname",
      "lastName": "mylastname",
      "phoneNumber": "000000000",
      "emailAddress": "test@example.com"
    },
    "productCode": "ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m",
    "validationType": "validateViaDns",
    "approverEmailAddress": "postmaster@example.com",
    "autoRenew": false
  }
}
EOF
```

Now you don't need all those quoting tricks.

---

Here's how I've tested the above solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use some sort of http debugging service to verify the content
# of the request.
url="https://eny65dku43a4g.x.pipedream.net"

# Create an example CSR
openssl req new -nodes \
  -keyout req.key \
  -out req.csr \
  -subject '/O=Example$Organization+Inc,CN=example.com'

csr=$(<req.csr)
authToken='example+password$here'

curl -i -X POST "$url" --data-binary @- <<EOF
{
  "authToken": "$authToken",
  "order": {
    "type": "DomainValidatedCertificateOrder",
    "csr": "$csr",
    "adminContact": {
      "title": "mytitle",
      "firstName": "myfirstname",
      "lastName": "mylastname",
      "phoneNumber": "X0000000",
      "emailAddress": "test@example.com"
    },
    "techContact": {
      "title": "mytitle",
      "firstName": "myfirstname",
      "lastName": "mylastname",
      "phoneNumber": "000000000",
      "emailAddress": "test@example.com"
    },
    "productCode": "ssl-geotrust-rapidssl-12m",
    "validationType": "validateViaDns",
    "approverEmailAddress": "postmaster@example.com",
    "autoRenew": false
  }
}
EOF
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! :) Suggesting here documents is a great idea! Unfortunately I just now realized that there's another problem that is bound to the CSR and the authToken: my token as well as my CSR contain "+" and "$". Somehow these chars aren't handled correctly which is why the server responds with "invalid API-Key". Do you have any idea how I can bypass this problem?

Comment: That shouldn't cause a problem. I've updated this answer to show how I've been testing it; the expected data appears to get delivered to the `POST` endpoint even if it contains the characters you mentioned. If you can create a runnable example that reproduces the behavior you're seeing I'd be happy to take a closer look.

Comment: Hi @larsks , thanks again for your quick reply! Since there are a few things like the token, the company name, the authToken as well as some other which I don't like posting for all, I would like to ask you, if I can somehow send it to you privately?